# Ejecutar el for cambiando una pedazo de string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas amigos , Saludos. El hecho es que me estoy iniciando en la prog. Y probando me encontré con algo curioso. Primero vean el código y luego la duda. Gracias de antemano

```
def body():
    print(temps)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    temps=list()
    for i in range(0,7):
        if i==0:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la primera temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)
    elif i==1:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la segunda temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)
        elif i==2:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la tercera temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)
        elif i==3:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la cuarta temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)
        elif i==4:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la quinta temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)
        elif i==5:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la sexta temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)
        elif i==6:
            datoIngresado=int(input("Ingrese la septima temperatura:  "))
            temps.append(datoIngresado)

body()
```

El hecho es que quiero hacer un for loop para pedir 7 datos equivalente a los 7 dias de la semana. Pero como ven tengo que utilizar 7 estructuras if comparándolas con la variable i de mi ciclo for. Esto lo hago para tener que mostrar por pantalla un string distinto de los demas. Es decir pasar "introduzca el primer dato" y asi para el segundo input"Introduzca el segundo dato." A que viene mi duda? Pues intento hacer un ciclo for en el que cada vez que se ejecute me cambie en esa palabra(que si primer,segundo y asi sucesivamente avance el for loop) sin tener que utilizar tantas estructuras if . Es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De ser posible, lo es... Si lo que buscas es una mejor manera de hacerlo, aqui te dejo una alternativa:

```
temps = list()
dias  = [ "primera", "segunda", "tercera", "cuarta", "quinta", "sexta", "septima" ]

def body():
    print(temps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(7):
        datoIngresado = int(input('Ingrese la %s temperatura: ' % dias[i]))
        temps.append(datoIngresado)
    body()
```

Esto básicamente ajusta los posibles 7 valores que vas a ingresar (Asumiendo que siempre serán 7, de lo contrario te recomiendo poner solo el numero).

Utilizando una lista `días` de la temperatura que pides, solo accede al indice `[i]` sin dejar de lado la lógica que implementas.

Answer (score 0):

Basta con recorrer un iterable con el contenido del input o su modificación para cada entrada de datos. En este caso se usa str.format() para formatear la cadena 
y se prescinde del uso de los indices que son más ineficientes y menos "pythónicos" que el `for in`:

```
temps=list()

for p in ('primera', 'segunda', 'tercera', 'cuarta', 'quinta', 'sexta', "séptima"):
    datoIngresado = int(input('Ingrese la {} temperatura: '.format(p))
    temps.append(datoIngresado)
```

Si usas Python >= 3.6 puedes usar los [literales de cadena formateados](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
temps=list()

for p in ('primera', 'segunda', 'tercera', 'cuarta', 'quinta', 'sexta', "séptima"):
    datoIngresado = int(input(f'Ingrese la {p} temperatura: '))
    temps.append(datoIngresado)
```